# Laravel sms verfiction api using firebase sms without using twilo or nexmoo

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel-5, firebase-authentication

Can i use firebase sms verfiction in a laravel restful api to send code to users without using third party libraries such as twilo or nexemo

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication's phone number verification is triggered by the signed-in user from the client-side SDKs, not from a server. So you can trigger sending the email from iOS, Android, Web, C++, Unity, and Flutter, but not from (server-side) Laravel).